How do I design a Multistage Amplifier with given specifications?
I have been tasked to design a multistage amplifier with the following specifications:
Gain(V/V) = 30,
Rin = 20 kohms,
Rout < 25 ohms,
Power supply = Dual +12V -12V,
Max Symmetrical Swing > 9Vpp (peak-to-peak),
lower 3dB down point < 200 Hz,
Upper 3dB down point > 5 kHz,
Rload = 200 ohms.
I already have done the analysis for the gain and 3dB down point for the lower frequency as shown by the schematic I provided, refer image below:

I do have some doubts because the simulation in ltspice is not working for either the AC sweep as well as the transient response. Of course, the transistors given in the schematic are not the correct ones, I am using three 2N7000's which I have extracted the Kn and Vt parameters for each for more accurate analysis.
However, I am not sure how to design for the upper 3dB down point, I am aware that I could place a capacitor from the gate to the drain to create dominant poles, however, I am not sure if I have to do this for all transistors or just one to create a single dominant pole.  How do I create or add into the design for the upper 3dB down point for a filter.
Note: Suggestions and/or similar examples are preferable as I want to be able to design this amplifier on my own. Here I will also attach my analysis via Imgur: https://imgur.com/a/Tqq92Pb

Just skimming I don't think you are in a place where you can design this on your own. I don't want to help with this specific design nor do I want to haul you off in another unwanted direction. The positive note I'll add is that a 200 mW output power goal is well-chosen for a first learning experience. It's perfect and I'm happy seeing that.

I'd like to know how you expect it to work, no sanity checks are made. How you can end up with 9Vpp into 200 ohm load with +/-12V supply and those 1.34 kohm resistances? Even a close approximation at DC would indicate you get from 12V and 1k resistor only 2V into 200 ohms. The resistor and capacitance values are also non-realistic, as in real life you can't buy most of the resistors and capacitors in those values anyway as they don't exist in those values and precision. Are you sure you were even supposed to build a Class A amplifier, or even use FETs instead of.BJTs?

So the reason for the R5, R11, R6, R8, R12, R7, R10 and R9 resistors is to get a specific bias point for each of the transistors which is why I have included them. This is my first multistage amplifier design, so I am not entirely familiar with how to go about the design process and how resistors and capacitors really affect my specifications. I have attached my analysis via Imgur, however, I will likely opt for a BJT design instead of a FET design.

Question to OP: the simulation in ltspice is not working for either the AC sweep as well as the transient response.  What does "not working" mean?  Does the simulation not run at all, or does the performance of the circuit not meet the specifications?

Suggestion to OP:  Change R15 to 1MEG (very high resistance), then repeat the simulations and post the result for all of the specifications you listed in the OP.

So by not working, when probing the output node (both before and after C3), LTSpice displays a flat dashed line at about -220dB and another solid linear -390dB. I suspect, that this has nothing to do with my command line and is likely due to bad design so I will revisit it, but I will try your suggestion
Note: The spice directive line I am using is (.ac dec 100 10 1000k). R15 is my load resistor.

Your design will work to the extent that it is a rather straightforward architecture: two common-source stages to provide (a) high input impedance and (b) voltage gain, and (c) a unity-gain source-follower at the output to provide the low output impedance.  The trick will be to ensure it meets the specifications.
I would not try to add capacitors to get the upper 3dB frequency to be precisely 5kHz; the specifications ask for an upper 3dB frequency greater than 5kHz. Similarly for these other parameters: lower 3dB frequency, output impedance, input impedance, and output voltage swing, the design should exceed the specifications for these parameters, not meet them precisely.  However, gain is a special parameter, best to precisely meet this to within, say, +/-5% of target.
Other factors to consider: many of the values presented in your schematic are not practically available, such as the signal coupling capacitors C1, C5, C6, and the AC gain setting capacitors C2, C4.  For example, I have never seen a capacitor with a value of 17.14uF. These should all be set to the next highest value in the E3, E6, or E12 standard values, for example, refer:
https://www.vishay.com/docs/28372/e-series.pdf
To trim the gain accurately, consider placing an extra resistor in series or parallel with the existing resistors that set the voltage gain.  These are, for example:
For M1: R7, R8, R12.
For M3: R5, R6, R11.
Some suggestions:

Increase the impedance of the input bias network, R1 & R2.  This will increase the amplifier input impedance.  There is no reason for this to have a lower impedance than the bias network of stage 2 (M1, R3 & R4).
Output voltage swing range will be most affected by the bias of M1 & M2, not by the bias of M3.  Focus on getting the Vgsth and gm values for these two stages correct for modelling purposes, then work on selecting the bias conditions accordingly.
What is the point of R10?  All it does is reduce the ability of M2 to provide the output voltage swing.  Consider reducing it to a very low value, say, 10 to 100Ω, or removing it altogether.
Focus on getting the output stage (M2) to meet the output specifications, ie: able to deliver 9Vp-p into a 200Ω load resistor.  Given the source resistor value I am seeing here at this time (R9=1.34kΩ), I find it difficult to believe this stage will meet this requirement without being very dependent upon the unit-to-unit variation of the MOSFETs you are using.  One important consideration for any electronic design is to ensure your design will work in real life where the parameters of semi-conductor components vary significantly with temperature and manufacturing tolerances.  Transistors in particular, whether they be BJT, MOSFET or JFET, all have various parameters that can vary widely from unit-to-unit, from manufacturer to manufacturer, and with temperature.
Once you have the output stage working well, then it should be quite simple to design the two preceding stages to meet the rest of the design specifications.

Personally, I would select the output stage to be a complementary push-pull type, however, if this is one of your first amplifier designs then I suggest you persevere with it for now.  Later on, may I suggest doing another design to meet the same specifications but this time using a complementary push-pull output stage; this exercise will demonstrate the significant benefits the push-pull stage has over the single transistor unity-gain stage you now have.
Good luck!

R9 won't even pull down properly against the load. The source follower is active on one side, passive on the other and R9 has to pull down through a 100 uF cap? Good luck.

@periblepsis  Yes, agreed.  However, this is probably a good "learning experience" for the OP.

It may be. I think the end of the pool here is too deep for the OP to get much from it. It will be brown mud and herculean for the OP to tease apart the Gordian Knot from where they obviously are at right now. But I don't have a working crystal ball, either, and may be wrong.
